# Set Different UINavigatiobar color for different UIViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a sample project with 3 UIViewController i want to change UINavigationbar color for each Viewcontroller.

I tried to use this code in ViewDidAppear method and its not changing.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg.png"]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact your code is for setting background for navigationBar, and it is true. But if you want to set color for each Viewcontroller navigation bar, in ViewController1 (say your first view controller) ViewDidAppear method add

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

in ViewController2 (say your second view controller) ViewDidAppear method add

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

then navigate through these controllers, you will see background color of navigation bar will be changed .

But your problem may be not setting ViewController custom class, you can set this from identity inspector.